# How can I retrieve a video file's playback rate (FPS) using PySide6?

Tags: python-3.x, pyside6

PySide6's QMediaPlayer has a property called playbackRate which can be set using QMediaPlayer.setPlaybackRate(), but this isn't the speed stored in the video file, it's a factor applied to the video's playback rate.

I can't find anything in the PySide6 or PyQt6 docs that explains how to read the video file to get the 'natural' playback rate.

I can guess at it like this:

```
## assumes video is 30 fps
playback_ratio = 24 / 30
speed = 1 / ratio
self.mediaPlayer.setPlaybackRate(speed)
```

But I'd rather read it from the file. Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Qt multimedia support does not currently seem to provide a reliable way to retrieve the video frame-rate. There is a [VideoFrameRate metadata attribute](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qmediametadata.html#details), but there's no guarantee that it will always be available (none of the files I tested had it). So it's probably best to use [opencv](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/) for this.

Comment: That was my conclusion, too. Thank you for the confirmation.